# Is there a way in Django to create and populate a column to the database with a string's length value?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a class/model in my models.py that can receive a textField. I want to add a column in my database that corresponds to the length of this textField. What is the best way of doing that?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your model that returns length of the TextField field.
Suppose your model is like this:

```
class ModelName(models.Model):
    str_field = models.TextField()
    
    @property
    def length(self):
        return (self.str_field)
```

And `my_model` is one object of this model class, below code returns length of str_field

`my_model.length`

This way doesn't add a column to database table but you can access the length of str_field.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a field that stores the character count value to your model:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
      my_text_field = models.TextField()
      char_count = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=0, blank=True, null=True)
```

And override the model `save` method to update the field on save:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.my_text_field:
       self.char_count = len(self.my_text_field)
    super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Adjust the field options (like `max_digits`) to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you want to use the length. The answer with the model property (`@property`) is good if you don't want to do complex queries involving the length, such as filtering by length, ordering, etc.

The solution with an extra database field solves the problem above, but it puts on you the duty of keeping the `char_count` column updated. If you need the length in your queries, a better way would be to use the database `LENGTH` function, which can be done readily in Django without changing your model. Examples, with a `Article` model that has a `text` `CharField`:

**Order by article text length:**

```
from django.db.models.functions import Length

sorted_qs = Article.objects.order_by(Length('text'))
```

If you print `str(sorted_qs.query)`, you can see `ORDER BY LENGTH("app_article"."text") ASC` in the query.

**Filter by length greater than `x`:**

```
Article.objects.annotate(text_len=Length('text')).filter(text_len__gte=x)
```

See the [doc on aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/).

If you have a large database table, consider adding an index on the length. In PostgreSQL, that would be:

```
CREATE INDEX app_article_text_length_idx ON app_article (LENGTH(text));
```